# How to create databases for setup and teardown with Mysql and EF C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In my current situation I'm trying to get test coverage of my linq to MySQL queries (I've had a few embarrassing errors in the last couple weeks.)

In my situation I have auto generated my .edmx files off of a very old MySQL database.  And I've got queries like:

```
return (from f in dbname.footable
        join b in dbname.bartable on b.key == f.key
        where b.something == x && f.other == y
        select b.value).Sum().GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

I don't want to do setup / teardowns on the actual shared server over the network, and it seems like the .edmx file should have all the schema information to recreate the database.

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to say, "Take this edmx and recreate it locally so I can start jamming test data in there."
I will also accept answers telling me that I'm doing it totally wrong and you should test your queries like X.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6307295

Comment: That's sorta related, but focuses on testing the business logic and excludes testing the actual queries.  I've already got my business logic covered, but I still had egg on my face when the queries returned unexpected results.  I also solemly swear to keep these tests out of the Test project and in a seperate TestIntegration project.

Comment: DbContext.Database.Create (or ObjectContext.CreateDatabase) will create a database using the schema defined in the .edmx assuming your version of the MySQL provider supports it.