# Entity Framework Load/Save Data

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

I am using SQLite with the Entity Framework in a C# Windows Form application. I have chosen to use an in-memory database. I'm trying to load a database file that exists on disk into memory. I'll also need to save what's in memory to the disk.

This seems like a relatively simple task but I can't find an elegant solution to it without hard-coding table creation and updating the queries whenever I change something (I.E: Not feasible)

If anyone can provide assistance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you may easily use `SQLite` [**in-memory database**](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)  with entity framework.

Look at the following threads as an initial guideline:

- [In Memory Sqlite Entity Framework Context](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/2604.aspx)
- [Integration Testing Entity Framework code first with in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5912128/1437962)

Comment: Thanks. So what I'm getting from this is that I'd have two methods: OpenSQLConnection and CloseSQLConnection. When the user loads a database file, I run OpenSQLConnection and when they close it or open another database, I run CloseSQLConnection. Is this right so far?

Still trying to figure out how to do the dump from the file to memory and vice verse but your links are helping!