# LocalDb for Unit Testing with Entity Framework 5.0 deployed to AppHarbor

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-5, appharbor, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is it possible to run unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 against a localDb that is built with Entity Framework 5.0 Code-First?  Currently our development is against a SQL Express Server Instance but this will not work with AppHarbor deployments since the Db is unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that using LocalDB would solve your problem. To use LocalDB, LocalDB still has to be installed on the machine running your unit tests and that may not be the case on AppHarbor.

Consider these resources for alternatives:

1. [Integration Testing Entity Framework code first with in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912128/integration-testing-entity-framework-code-first-with-in-memory-database)  (use SQL Server CE using a file in unit test directory)
2. [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com) (let's you create schema and run unit tests in memory without touching the file system - probably preferable)

Comment: I was able to get the .sdf working (partially) in the unit test scenario.  The issue now is .sdf does not allow for stored procedure creation so I'm only able to partially test the database.

Comment: You should probably move whatever logic you have in your stored procedures into your application code to make it more portable. You should also consider mocking the database in your unit tests so that your unit tests don't have to touch the file system. It sounds like what you're doing is more akin to integration tests than unit tests.

Comment: Yes you are correct these are more in the spirit of integration tests, but unfortunately given the fact that with continuous deployment the unit ("integration") tests are the only gate keeper.  Moving logic from database to application tier never seems like a good idea when it's primary reason for existing is set-based filtering. The transfer of unnecessary data per request seems more costly than resolving portability issue.

Comment: If you stored procedures are just filtering, then that's an even better case for just moving that logic to Entity Framework. If you have an `.Where(x => x.Age > 25)` that get's translated to an efficient SQL `where` clause by Entity Framework and no more data is transferred to your app.