# Appharbor don't inserts connection string from Sequelizer

Tags: appharbor

I have a ASP.NET MVC project with integrity test. In test app.config I have a

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="localhost" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=repaem;
Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I've created Connectionstring alias "localhost" in Sequelizer MSSQL configuration. But when I deploy, tests fails with message "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "repaem" requested by the login. The login failed." Probably, connection string remains the same...

I have tried to create ConnectionFactory manually, as described in http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer.

```
var uriString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSERVER_URI"];
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
SqlConnectionFactory factory = new SqlConnectionFactory(uri.Host, uri.AbsolutePath.Trim('/'), uri.UserInfo.Split(':').First(), uri.UserInfo.Split(':').Last());

Bind<IDatabase>().To<Database>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("factory", factory);
```

but ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSERVER_URI"] is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the database while executing unit tests? That's not supported, the connectionstring is only inserted once the code is deployed.

Here are some additional resources:

- [LocalDb for Unit Testing with Entity Framework 5.0 deployed to AppHarbor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483584/localdb-for-unit-testing-with-entity-framework-5-0-deployed-to-appharbor/14491854#14491854)
- [Unit test configuration value](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1292-unit-test-configuration-values)