# Unittesting with EF using a separate database for each test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, multiple-databases

When unittesting with Fluent NHibernate I create a new session for each test, and that session has its own factory that creates a sqlite-database where the filename equals the fully qualified testname (from the TestContext). This always gives me a clean database, and no conflicts from the unittests running in parallel. I store these databases on a ramdrive, so I have the same speed as an in-memory database, but is also able to see the resulting data afterwards.

Is it possible to achieve this using EF Code first and SQL Ce?
I'm hoping the solution to this problem also could enable me to use EF with two databases, one file-based local db for offline access, that synchronizes to a cloud based database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration Testing Entity Framework code first with in-memory database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912128/integration-testing-entity-framework-code-first-with-in-memory-database)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. I know how to use a single SQL Ce db, I need to use one for each test, which most often equals one per thread running unittests (1-4).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to achieve this:

```
public class Db : DbContext {
    private static SqlCeConnectionFactory factory = 
               new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

    public static Db Create(string filename) {
        return new Db(factory.CreateConnection(@"Data Source=" + filename));
    }

    public Db(DbConnection conn)
        : base(conn, true) {
    }

    public DbSet<object> TableName {get; set;}
}
```

In the unittest code I can then use:

```
private Db CreateDb() {
    return Db.Create("R:\\"+TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName + 
                     TestContext.TestName + ".sdf");
}

[TestMethod]
public void StoreAndRetrieve() {
    using (var db = CreateDb()) {
        ...
    }
}
```